# How do I completely remove Visual Studio 11 Beta, before installing Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

When I try to install VS2012, the installer suggests I should install it where the old VS11Beta was installed - and that tells me there's some leftovers from VS11Beta that needs to be cleaned.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order you have to uninstall:

1. Microsoft Visual Studio 11 Ultimate Beta
2. Microsoft Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview Pre-Clean Tool
3. Microsoft Silverlight 5 Beta SDK
4. Microsoft Silverlight 4 SDK
5. Microsoft Web Deploy dbSqlPackage Provider Nov 2011
6. Microsoft Visual Studio 11 SharePoint Developer Tools Beta enu Language Pack
7. Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools, RC0 - enu
8. Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Management Objects RC0 (x64)
9. Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Management Objects RC0
10. Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server 2012 RC0 (x64)
11. Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server 2012 RC0
12. Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 SP1 ENU CTP1
13. Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB RC0
14. Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools Build Utilities Mar 2012
15. Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Transact-SQL Language Service RC0
16. Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Command Line Utilities RC0
17. Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client RC0
18. Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Data-Tier App Framework
19. Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Transact-SQL Compiler Service RC0
20. Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Transact-SQL ScriptDom RC0 Prerequisites for SSDT RC0
21. Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x64)
22. Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86)
23. Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3
24. Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages WCF RIA Services V1.0 SP2
25. Microsoft Web Platform Installer 4.0
26. IIS 7.5 Express
27. Microsoft Web Deploy 3.0
28. The Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 Developer Beta Multi-Targeting Pack
29. The Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack

Here the complete reference i have used from microsoft:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2710678

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can cleanup after VS11Beta

- First - open 'appwiz.cpl' from Run menu (Win+R).
- Remove all occurances of 'Visual Studio 11 Beta*' from the list
- Go to your user folder %USERPROFILE%\Documents and delete the 'Visual Studio 11 Beta' folder
- Then open 'appwiz.cpl' again, and remove the .NET Framework 4.5 Beta occurances.
- Go to the Program Files destination, you installed VS11Beta, and remove the 'Visual Studio 11 Beta' folder
- Reboot your machine

---

- If your VS2010 now prompts you with 'Unknown Error' at startup, you have to install either VS2012 (which includes .Net Framework 4.5) or .Net Framework 4.5 stand-alone.
- If your VS2010 now prompts you with 'Environment Package Window Management did not load correctly', you need to Repair your VS2010 installation.